# what is the best way to create a notifications card vertical carousel with animating the first card to slidin?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, swiper.js

I am trying to make an automatic notification cards, the card should slid in from the right of the screen with animation the second card will slid in the same way and push the previous card down, exactly like this website https://muzzleapp.com/

i have tried to create it with swiperjs but i cant animate the card to slide in from the left and the auto play of the carousel is not like the one in the website https://muzzleapp.com/
here is my code

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
   
  direction: "vertical",
  grabCursor: true,
  centeredSlides: true,
  slidesPerView: "auto",
  reverseDirection: true,
  loop: true,

  slidesPerView: 6,
  spaceBetween: 10,
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    clickable: true,
  },
  coverflowEffect: {
    rotate: 50,
    stretch: 0,
    depth: 100,
    modifier: 1,
    slideShadows: true,
  },
  

  autoplay: {
    delay: 1500,
  },
});
```

and this is the html

```
 <div class="col-lg-5">
                    <img class="main-img" src="./Assest/Group 14.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <div class="swiper-container">
                        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                                    <img src="./Assest/avatar1.png" class="avatar" alt="">
                                    <div class="d-flex flex-column mt-3">
                                        <h2 class="name">Derek Chin</h2>
                                        <p class="card-info">Aiseh new PS5 ah, swee ah bro. But now pokai how?</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                                    <img src="./Assest/avatar1.png" class="avatar" alt="">
                                    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                                        <h2 class="name">Derek Chin</h2>
                                        <p class="card-info" class="card-info">Aiseh new PS5 ah, swee ah bro. But now
                                            pokai how?</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                                    <img src="./Assest/avatar1.png" class="avatar" alt="">
                                    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                                        <h2 class="name">Derek Chin</h2>
                                        <p class="card-info">Aiseh new PS5 ah, swee ah bro. But now pokai how?</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

any one has a better way for me to reach my goal please ,,,, thank you

Comment: What is this? A question for a "how to"? Or do you have an actual problem, which then would require an [mcve] with more details (what it is supposed to happen, what happens instead, any error messages)...

Comment: *what is the best way* - probably using a decent plugin which has the option(s) you want.  You could try [toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr).  But otherwise you might like to rephrase to "how can I do this" question rather than "what's the best way to do this" as "best way" is opinion-based which is off topic at SO so your question will likely be closed.